# Matlab and .NET Interaction

Tags: .net, matlab, interaction

I'm having an issue interacting between Matlab and .NET. I've managed to call .NET methods from Matlab code and vice versa. **However**, if I call a .NET method that, in turn, instantiates a Matlab object, it crashes (with a type initialization exception).

Think about this scenario: a .NET assembly is interacting with a Matlab dll that was deployed for .NET (not native) by Matlab's *deploytool*. Now, when I'm loading the above .NET dll in a Matlab program everything is ok until I run a method that utilizes the other Matlab dll. Only then everything crashes.

The exact message is:

***Warning: Cannot initialize MATLAB Compiler-generated software component in MATLAB. MATLAB Compiler-generated software components cannot be used from within MATLAB.***

Please don't offer not to use Matlab-.NET-Matlab architecture, it's not an option.

Thank you very much (I promise to accept the answer that solves the problem :-)),

Yaron.

Comment: When MATLAB specifically tells you this can not be done, I don't know why you're insistent on finding a way to get this working.